# Elearning/CBT / Animation using HTML5, CSS3 and Jquery (without using Flash)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a attached flash animation CBT in HTML5 using XML, Jquery and css. Can anyone help me out how to make this in HTML without using flash animation/video. Also want to use same control like (next, back, volume, play, pause, replete, slide 1 of 14 etc.)

Also please suggest some demo and example of CBT/E-learning in HTML5.

[image]

Thanks a lot. I am new to HTML5 and jquery.

Comment: The image doesn't really tell us anything about what animation you're trying to do.  If it's just a slide, no problem, but if that lady is supposed to start dancing or something...well, that's a whole other thing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late, but I think Phyzixlabs software offers exactly what you're looking for... You can see examples of  html5 applets from here: http://colabopad.blogspot.com/2011/03/public-release-of-simupad.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

jquery slideshow plugins should give you some headstart http://graphicalerts.com/20-best-jquery-slideshow-image-photo-gallery-plugins/